# Print dots on screen coordinates C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, drawing, system.drawing

In my application , i want to print / draw dots (or any shapes) on the given coordinates by the application.I want to draw the dots / shape on the desktop screen.

Are there any function in C# to print/draw the dots on given screen coordinates ?

IDE - Visual Studio 2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Help us help you. Give us some code that you have written for the problem so far. That will show us you have tried something instead of us just giving you the answer.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to achieve. Do you want to draw anywhere on the desktop or just within the window(s) of your application?

Comment: I ant show some kind of dots on the given screen coordinate (To check the screen coordinate visually).I want to draw the dots / shape on the desktop screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using System.Drawing;    
    Graphics g;
    using (g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))

        {

             g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, x,y, 20, 20);

         }
```

This piece of code code worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can draw your shapes on transparent top-level window. See [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx).